# How Can I Make A Slide-Out Using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to create a slide out which slides out automatically on page load, stays for 5 seconds and then slides in and show a button which slide it out again when clicked or hovered.

Comment: http://101helper.blogspot.com/2015/09/jquery-slide-down-mobile-menu-for-blogger.html here is my blog you can see a demo here which I have tried yet.. its floating fine but it goes down at the end of the page. I want it to stop when the post footer reaches.

Comment: On that page you can see "recommended articles" its floating but floats to the end of the page I want it to stop at the post footer

Comment: Hi @FahimRaza please take the time to read this page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to provide all the informations needed in your question, including code.

Comment: I don't have any code so I didn't share it.

Answer (score 2):

I've prepared a [little fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jm2b2mqa/) that I think does what you're looking for.

```
<style>
#popup {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-150px;
  background: grey;
  position:absolute;
  left: -300px;
  -transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#popup.active {
  left:0;
}

button { 
  float:right;
}
</style>

<div id="popup">
    <button id="close">Close</button>
</div>

<script>
  setTimeout(function() {
     document.getElementById('popup').className="active";
  }, 5000);

  document.getElementById('close').onclick=function () {
      document.getElementById('popup').className="";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This one is working fine but it doesn't slide in after 5 seconds. I want it to slide out then slide in after 5 seconds and show a button which can be clicked to show it again

Comment: I just gave you enough to start from, I'm sure you can adapt it to your needs. This forum is to help resolve specific programming problems, as opposed to building your website for you.